# ng test not working after upgrade to Karma 2.0.0

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, karma-runner

Yesterday I upgraded Angular from v4.4 to v5.2 and Karma from v1.7.1 to v2.0.0. Since doing this I can't run *ng test*.

I can run the tests using the *karma start myconfigfile.js --single-run* and they all pass correctly, but when I try *ng test*, the browser opens but hangs after displaying 'Karma - starting'. There is no console output.

I've tried both Chrome and ChromeHeadless for the browser but have run out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

Config:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-spec-reporter'),
            require('karma-junit-reporter'),
            require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
        ],
        client: {
            clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
        files: [
            { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
        },
        mime: {
            'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx']
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'cobertura'],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
            'report-config': {
                cobertura: {
                    file: 'coverage.xml'
                }
            }
        },
        angularCli: {
            environment: 'dev'
        },
        reporters: ['spec', 'kjhtml', 'junit', 'coverage-istanbul'],
        junitReporter: {
            outputDir: '',
            outputFile: 'test-results.xml',
            useBrowserName: false
        },
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
        singleRun: true,
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,
        browserDisconnectTolerance: 5
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this in future, it looks like it was a dependency issue. An npm install sorted it out.

Comment: What did you install to fix it?

Comment: I didn't install anything extra. 'npm install' will just install all the dependencies that are in your package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying same with **angular 5,karma 2.0.0, karma-chrome-launcher 2.2.0** on windows 10 machine and wasted entire day to figure it out why chrome is not capturing.

You have to make custom chrome header although documents says only
**browsers: ['ChromeHeadless']**  would work but its not working.

Please make custom header like this:

```
    customLaunchers: {
        ChromeHeadlessCustom: {
            base: 'ChromeHeadless', // browser
            flags: [
                '--no-sandbox', // needed to run test  case in windows also
            ],
        },
    }
```

Then give custom header reference in browser tag:

```
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessCustom']
```

After this its working like charm. :)